# replacing items in tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have to write a code that will switch the first item in a tuple with the last one, unless there is only one item. I understand in tuples this cannot be done, but it can be done in a list. So in my code I am changing the tuple to be a list. 
after running the code it should look like this:

```
>>>switchItems((6,4,8,3,7,9,4))
(4,4,8,3,7,9,6) 
>>>switchItems((“hi” , 23))
(23, “hi”) 
>>>switchItems((89,))
(89,)
```

My code doesn't do this. It returns a list in between and I don't really know how to make it work properly, this is my code:

```
switchItems(tuple):
    new = list(tuple)
    return new[-1],new [1:-2],new[0]
```

And it returns this:

```
    >>>switchItems((6,4,8,3,7,9,4))
        (4, [4, 8, 3, 7], 6)'
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one way to fix your code.

```
def switchItems(tup):
    if len(tup) > 1:
        new = list(tup)
        new[0], new[-1] = new[-1], new[0]
        return tuple(new)
    return tup
```

Length check helps avoid possible errors and needles `tuple` to `list` to `tuple` conversion.

Now, let's talk a bit about your problems.

- The function switchItems was not properly defined. In Python you are supposed to use `def` (or `lambda`) to define a function, but I'm sure that is an artifact of copy-pasting.
- You shouldn't use argument names that shadow built-in names, i.e. don't use `tuple` as an argument name.
- According to PEP8 you should avoid using CamelCase to name functions in Python, e.g. `switchItems` should be `switch_items`. This is not enforced, but highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The length does not matter, you just have to swap the first and last elements:

```
def switch_items(t): # use lowercase  and underscores for function names
    t = list(t)
    t[0],t[-1] = t[-1],t[0]
    return tuple(t)
```

You would maybe want to catch an empty tuple though:

Or slice and check the len:

```
def switch_items(t):
    return  t[-1:] + t[1:-1] + t[0:1] if len(t) > 1 else t
```

Comment: Length check lets you avoid needless `tuple` to `list` to `tuple` conversion. And the second one is not memory efficient, though it is concise and beautiful.

Comment: @EliKorvigo, if the length is one then we won't have to worry about the time it will take calling list on a tuple with a single element, I would be more worried about getting an empty tuple or something not iterable at all

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a copy of switched tuple. (Certainly you won't get it in place)

```
def switchItems(t):
    if len(t) > 1:
        return tuple(t[-1] + list(t[1:-2]) + t[0])
    return t
```

Comment: You can only return once from a function so you don't need the else.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
def switchItems(my_tuple): 
    l1 = list(my_tuple)  # Convert to a list
    if l1:  # check if not empty to prevent 'list index out of range' error 
        l1[0], l1[-1] = l1[-1], l1[0]  #swap first and last items

    return tuple(l1)
```

You pass the tuple to `switchItems()` function. The function converts the tuple to a list. It then swaps the first and last element using indices `0` and `-1` if list obtained in previous step was not empty.  This is done to prevent `list index out of range` error on accessing first and last element.